# What is the actual PostgreSQL download URL for windows?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install PostgreSQL via Ansible on a Windows machine, meaning I'll need a URL. I know this shows me a [download link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), and I can usually right-click on the link and get the actual URL. Clocking on that line takes you to [this page](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-tutorial-resources-training?cid=437), and right-clicking on the [start the download now](https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1257713) link on that page doesn't give me a direct URL either, but a link to a javescript. I even looked a the HTML source in Brave browser Developer tools. I even found an [example here](https://blog.dbi-services.com/getting-started-with-ansible-download-the-postgresql-sources-compile-and-install/), but the ftp url shown there doesn't have Windows installers. I also searched for "Postgres download URL" here, to no avail.

What the heck is the actual download URL, say for version 13?

Comment: Normally you would pull from a local copy that you update manually based on testing/development cycles. Reduces load on the main product download sites when you bring up 20 database installations, your deployments don't fail if files move, become unavailable or the website is down and you don't deploy things you haven't tested against.

Comment: We have an ftp site that has it, this is just one option for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page you [linked to](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), if you click on the "Download" it takes you to this page](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-tutorial-resources-training?cid=437) which typically starts the download automatically.

However, there is a message

> If your download does not begin automatically, [start the download now](https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1257713)

which is the direct link to the installer (in this case for 13.3)

Comment: I did that, and if you right-click on that link, you get this link https://sbp.enterprisedb.com/getfile.jsp?fileid=1257713. I expect a `postgresql-x.y.z-x64.exe` (or `*.msi`) in the path? that link essentially runs a javascript it seems.

Comment: I'll be damned, that link worked in Ansible! thanks. I shoulda tried first before asking.

Comment: If you want to automate things, then why not download the ZIP binaries instead? https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries